# Frequency Detection on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, frequency, sampling, frequency-analysis

I want to be able to detect a high frequency (60 - 70 kHz) on a iOS application written in Swift. However, I don't know where I should start. I know that on a typical iPhone the sampling rate is about 44 kHz and by the Nyquist Theorem, I can only detect frequencies at about half of the sampling rate. So how would I go about trying to detect a high frequency if my sampling rate is lower than it.

Comment: Human ears are able to hear up to roughly 20 KHz (and that's why we encode at a minimum of 44 KHz BTW, yes it's Nyquist, 20*2+margin). And most microphones are unable to record anything higher than 18 KHz. So, to detect 60 KHz... forget it immediately. ;)

Comment: Sorry. It's like trying to measure milliseconds with a watch that only shows seconds... not possible.